# How to get To address in Exchange Web service in .NET?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I want to get the To Address of mail in Exchange Web service.

Here is my code:

```
string _ToAddress =string.Empty;

foreach (Item _MailItem in findResults.Items)    
{
     _ToAddress = _MailItem.DisplayTo.ToString();
}
```

It returns alias of the mail Address like this My_Mail_Id
Instead of My_Mail_Id@MyDomain.com

How to Get Mail Address as full address

Answer (score 0):

To get the To address you need to load the [ToRecipients](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchangewebservices.messagetype.torecipients%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) property of the mail item. This property stores a collection of recipients. The property has an address field which holds the email address of the recipient.

Thanks,
Niall